# Hanoi towers with nPegs > 3 (easier game for kids)

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a set of 3 pegs for the Hanoi Towers game:

```
int[][] pegs = new int[N_PEGS][N_DISCS];
```

So peg 1 is `pegs[0]`, peg2 is `pegs[1]`, peg3 is `pegs[2]`.

Given the `id` of two peg positions, I need to get the `id` of the other one, as such:

```
if (startFromPeg == 0 && endAtPeg == 1) {
    useAsTempPeg = 2;
}
```

In other words, of the set S = {0, 1, 2} I want the element left after considering the parameters {s1, s2}.

For a set of 3 pegs, I can do this with easy math, unless I am mistaken:

```
useAsTempPeg = N_PEGS - startFromPeg - endAtPeg;
```

This seems to always give the correct result:

```
3 - 0 - 1 = 2 (ok)
3 - 0 - 2 = 1 (ok)
3 - 1 - 2 = 0 (ok)
```

How can I make this formula general and play the game with `N_PEGS > 3`? (it would be a much easier game that way, but that's intended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use {Sum_of_peg_indices} - {Sum_of_pegs_selected}. So for 3 you have (0+1+2)=3={Sum_of_peg_indices} and so you get the formula you mention.

Comment: Does this work with 4 pegs? How best to break the tie now that I have 2 choices of "temp"?

Comment: Maybe I did not interpret your question correctly. I thought you are asking how to get the index of the other peg if you choose 3 pegs.

Comment: @Robottinosino 4 pegs? I don't think that will be Tower of Hanoi anymore, though you can increase no of disks

Comment: @Mr.Anubis There is a solution for any number of disks if you are given only 3 pegs. No matter how many disks you have you will never need 4 pegs. If I get the question correctly it is not about the game but rather focuses on how does one compute the index of the remaining peg.

Comment: I still don't get what you wanted to say, it seems you repeated the lines I wrote except last sentence.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis I understood your comment as -  this will not be Hanoi Towers anymore but might make sense for larger number of disks. Probably I got what you meant wrong.